# Replacing a placeholder value with uniquely named input fields

Tags: coldfusion

I have the following code where I have a placeholder inside my saved content. I want to replace the placeholder value with an input field. I am able to do that successfully. However, I need to rename all of the input checkbox fields differently like 1,2,3,4, but without using the JSoup library because that is kind of overkill here.  Is there anything else I can try?

```
<cfsavecontent variable="h">
    <cfoutput>#mytable.h#</cfoutput>
</cfsavecontent>
<cfset h= Replace(h,"[Check Box]","<input type='checkbox' name='abc' id='abc'>","all")>
```

The above creates checkboxes with the same name, which I do not want.

Comment: You're doing just one pass on your `h` variable and replacing all iterations of `[Check Box]` with the same thing. Try looping over your variable and only changing one at a time.

Comment: Why don't you skip the placeholder and get your savecontent to produce what you actually want?

Answer (score 2):

This is ugly and kind of brute-force-ish, but it should give you an idea of one way you can approach this issue.

```
<!--- Whatever your h value comes from --->
<cfset h = "[Check Box] Some text. <br>
    [Check Box] Some text. <br>
    [Check Box] Some text. <br>
    [Check Box] Some text. <br>
    [Check Box] Some text. <br>
    [Check Box] Some text. <br> 
    [Check Box] Some text. <br>
    [Check Box] Some text. <br>
">

<!--- 
    We replace the searched for text with a single character delimiter 
    so that we can count elements. We also append a nonsense character 
    to the string to make sure that if our searh string is the first 
    thing in the full string, it will still get replaced. 
--->
<cfset changeDelims = replace('a' & h,"[Check Box]","|","All")>
<!--- 
    Now we can count how many elements are in the main string. This 
    will tell us how many times we need to replace our substring. 
--->
<cfset howMany = listLen(changeDelims,"|")-1>

<!--- 
    Now loop through your string for the number of times we have that
    substring and replace it. 
--->
<cfloop from="1" to="#howMany#" index="i">
    <cfset replaceStr = "<input type='checkbox' name='abc#i#' id='abc#i#'>")>
    <cfset h = replace(h,"[Check Box]", replaceStr)>
</cfloop> 

<!--- Which gives us.... ---->
<cfoutput>#h#</cfoutput>
```